# Умеет ли CreateIoCompletionPort() слушать несколько сокетов ожидающих подключений?

Tags: windows, c++

Умеет ли `CreateIoCompletionPort()` слушать несколько сокетов ожидающих подключений?

Comment: В MSDN написано "...with one or more file handles..."

Comment: Ну так. Как запихнуть туда много соккетов и ждать по ним данные примеров много. Меня интересует пример с соккетами после Liste() ожидающих подключений.

Comment: После `Listen`, но перед `Accept`? Такого не существует, на сколько я знаю. Если хотите контролировать очередь ожидающих сокетов самостоятельно, ставьте в `backlog`(у `listen`) значение `1` и формируйте очередь на свой вкус и цвет.